# Facebook Feed Dialog Direct URL goes to chat page instead of feed page if the user has to log in

Tags: facebook, url, dialog, feed

When the FB.ui call with method feed after working for 4 months started returning a "Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options" error. I changed to the Direct URL call which worked fine until today.

If the user is logged into Facebook the direct URL works correctly and goes to the feed dialog page allowing the user to share and return to my mobile web application. However, if the user is not logged in, the user gets directed to the login page (which is correct) and after logging in the get the chat page. If the click/tap the back button they get the feed dialog.

I'd like to report this as a bug to Facebook, but I cannot create a but (no create link) nor affirm that I'm getting the same bug as another bug report.

Comment: _“but I cannot create a bug”_ – you have to start typing in the search field, then the option to create an new one will appear as last item in the list of results.

Comment: Nope. Typing in the search field does not show me a create link next to the search field or anywhere else that I can see. However I did see the bug was reported by another developer. I would have liked to say that I can reproduce the error too, but couldn't see how to do that either. Looks like the Facebook "bug" site has bugs.